# Trying to make a UICollectionView programmatically iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

We are trying to make a `UICollectionView` for iOS 7 programmatically however, we are running into problems for the cells to show up. Here is our code. We know that the collection gets made and the `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` gets called and the `numberOfItemsInSection` gets called. However the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` does not or the `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`.
What are we missing here?

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setUpCollectionView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) setUpCollectionView
{
    collectionViewLayout = [[UICollectionViewLayout  alloc] init];
    teamCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds collectionViewLayout: collectionViewLayout];
    [teamCollectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier: @"cellIdentifier"];
    teamCollectionView.dataSource = self;
    teamCollectionView.delegate = self;


    teamCollectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [self addSubview: teamCollectionView];

}

/**
 * STARTS THE COLLECTION VIEW FOR THE VIEW
 */

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath: indexPath];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{      
    return 15;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(50, 50);
}

/**
 * ENDS THE COLLECTION VIEW FOR THE VIEW
 */
```

Comment: It seems we needed to initialize the collection view with a proper layout. The layout we used in the code above was valid however, it never said what to do with the cells. We ended up with a UICollectionViewFlowLayout and it worked.